# javascript error- Chrome say it's not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I have a js file and a html. From the html I call the function on click.

My Problem is- The specification_none works, But Chrome prompts the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: specification_existing is not a function

So what is the Problem? Why doesn't the other function work?

Here is my code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

        if ($('#radio_specification_none').attr("checked")){

            $("#specification_existing_box").hide();    // hide existing_spec
            $("#specification_new_box").hide();         // hide new_spec

            $('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;          // set existing specifications to default value

            $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);        // set existing spec. size the required attribute to false
            $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);        // set for new spec. the required attribute to false
        }
        if ($('#radio_specification_existing').attr("checked")){

            $("#specification_existing_box").show();            // hide existing_spec
            $("#specification_new_box").hide();                 // hide create new_spec

            $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', true);        // set for new_spec the required attribute to true
            $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);            // set for new_spec the required attribute to false
        }
        if ($('#radio_specification_new').attr("checked")){

            $("#specification_new_box").show();                // show new_spec
            $("#specification_existing_box").hide();           // hide existing_spec

            $('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;          // set existing specifications to default value

            $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);        // set for new_spec the required attribute to false
            $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', true);             // set for new_spec the required attribute to true
        }

    // ---- show and hide sizes ----- //

    // children sizes (default)
    $('#radio_child').change(function(){
        if (!$('#radio_child').checked){        // change if other user pick other button; this one is then false

            $("#child_sizes").show();           // show child sizes
            $("#konfektion_sizes").hide();      // hide adult sizes
        }

        $('#select_konfektion_sizes')[0].selectedIndex = 0;     // set adult size to "Wählen..."

        $('#select_child_sizes').prop('required',true);         // set for child size the required attribute to true
        $('#select_konfektion_sizes').prop('required',false);   // set for adult size the required attribute to false
    });
    // adult sizes
    $('#radio_adult').change(function(){        // change if other user pick other button; this one is then false
        if (!$('#radio_adult').checked){

            $("#child_sizes").hide();           // hide child sizes
            $("#konfektion_sizes").show();      // show adult sizes
        }

        $('#select_child_sizes')[0].selectedIndex = 0;          // set children size to default value

        $('#select_child_sizes').prop('required',false);        // set for child size the required attribute to false
        $('#select_konfektion_sizes').prop('required',true);    // set for adult size the required attribute to true
    });



    // triggers
    $('#radio_child').trigger('change');                        // trigger change (child radio) for one time, if document load

});

function specification_none(element){

  alert("specification_none");

    // change the checked attribute
    $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
    $('#specification_existing_box').prop('checked', "");
    $('#specification_new_box').prop('checked', "");

    //hide other specifications
    $("#specification_existing_box").hide();    // hide existing_spec
    $("#specification_new_box").hide();         // hide new_spec

    // set existing specifications to default value
    $('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;


    // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
    $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', true);
    // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
    $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);
    $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);
}

function specification_existing(element){

  alert("specification_existing");

    // change the checked attribute
    $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
    $('#specification_none_box').prop('checked', "");
    $('#specification_new_box').prop('checked', "");

    // show existing box
    $("#specification_existing_box").show();    // hide existing_spec

    //hide other specifications
    $("#specification_none_box").hide();    // hide existing_spec
    $("#specification_new_box").hide();         // hide new_spec

    // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
    $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', true);
    // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
    $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', false);
    $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);
}

function specification_new(element){

  alert("specification_new");

    // change the checked attribute
    $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
    $('#specification_existing_box').prop('checked', "");
    $('#specification_none_box').prop('checked', "");

    //hide other specifications
    $("#specification_existing_box").hide();    // hide existing_spec
    $("#specification_none_box").hide();         // hide new_spec

    // set existing specifications to default value
    $('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;


    // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
    $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', true);
    // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
    $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);
            $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/my.js') }}" ></script>

 <!--clothes specification-->
    <div class="raidio_box_specifications">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td><p>Besonderheit:  </p></td>
                <td  class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner last_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_new" name="specification" class="custom-control-input" onclick="specification_new(this)">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_new">neue erstellen</label>
                </td>
                <td class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_existing" name="specification" class="custom-control-input" onclick="specification_existing(this)" {% if clothing_info[0].clothes_specification_id != 1 %} checked="checked" {% else %}  {% endif %}>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_existing" >vorhandene</label>
                </td>
                <td class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_none" name="specification" class="custom-control-input" onclick="specification_none(this)" {% if clothing_info[0].clothes_specification_id == 1 %} checked="checked" {% else %}  {% endif %}>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_none">keine</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me out here

Comment: are you loading `my.js` or is the function wrapped inside another function (like `window.onload=function(){ /* Your code here */ }`

Comment: Are you sure that you added your js file to the html page correctly? eg `<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>`. You can check it in Chrome dev tools in Network tab

Comment: @user1496463 _"...The specification_none works..."_

Comment: The markup is invalid. There's no opening `<tr>`

Comment: @ user1496463 I tried it inside and outside on document ready.

@ Kirill Yes

Comment: Can you add how you include the js file, and the full `my.js` file? Will be able to isolate issue with these details.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] because I cannot reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n1ncf1gc/

Comment: @Luca Oh, btw, if specification_none works, did you try to reload your page without cache? `CTRL + SHIFT + R` in chrome

Comment: you are maybe overriding the method `specification_existing` again, hence the error message. see my answer below.

Comment: @ Kirill Yes. I Update my question with the full .js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant figure out why this is not working. I made a running version and it runs great.

But since you use the `onclick` props of the HTML elements, there can be allot of things going wrong here. Since you are using jQuery consider binding the callbacks via jQuery's `.click()` method (see below).

This method can reduce errors coming with scoping etc greatly and you don't have to pollute the global JS space.

Potentially you have some script thats just sets the function `specification_existing` to anything else like this:

`specification_existing = 'accidentally changed specification_existing'`

This is also indicated by the error you get:

- `... is not a function` indicates that the "variable" exsists, but is not a callable function
- `... is not defined` indicates that the "variable" you try to call is unknown

Here are some things that could help you allot with this kind of problems:

- keep your global space clean. exec your code in `(function(){/* your code */})()` or similar fashion.
- always declare and init variables (`var myLocalVar`) or use strict mode
- try to not mix JS code into your HTML. Use jQuery or better the vanilla JS API: `jQuery.on('click', ()=>{[...]})` `element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{[...]})`

```js
$(function(){
  function specification_none(element) {
    console.log('specification_none')

      // change the checked attribute
      $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
      $('#specification_existing_box').prop('checked', "");
      $('#specification_new_box').prop('checked', "");

      //hide other specifications
      $("#specification_existing_box").hide(); // hide existing_spec
      $("#specification_new_box").hide(); // hide new_spec

      // set existing specifications to default value
      //$('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;


      // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
      $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', true);
      // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
      $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);
      $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);
  }

  function specification_existing(element) {
    console.log('specification_existing')
      // change the checked attribute
      $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
      $('#specification_none_box').prop('checked', "");
      $('#specification_new_box').prop('checked', "");

      // show existing box
      $("#specification_existing_box").show(); // hide existing_spec

      //hide other specifications
      $("#specification_none_box").hide(); // hide existing_spec
      $("#specification_new_box").hide(); // hide new_spec

      // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
      $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', true);
      // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
      $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', false);
      $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', false);
  }

  function specification_new(element) {
    console.log('specification_new')

      // change the checked attribute
      $(element).prop('checked', "checked");
      $('#specification_existing_box').prop('checked', "");
      $('#specification_none_box').prop('checked', "");

      //hide other specifications
      $("#specification_existing_box").hide(); // hide existing_spec
      $("#specification_none_box").hide(); // hide new_spec

      // set existing specifications to default value
      //$('#specification_existing_box')[0].selectedIndex = 0;


      // set the required attribute from THIS input to true
      $('#specification_new_box').prop('required', true);
      // set the required attribute from the other inputs to false
      $('#specification_existing_box').prop('required', false);
      $('#specification_none_box').prop('required', false);
  }

  $('#radio_specification_new').click(specification_new)
  $('#radio_specification_existing').click(specification_existing)
  $('#radio_specification_none').click(specification_none)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="raidio_box_specifications">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <p>Besonderheit: </p>
              </td>
              <td class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner last_radio">
                  <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_new" name="specification" class="custom-control-input">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_new">neue erstellen</label>
              </td>
              <td class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner">
                  <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_existing" name="specification" class="custom-control-input" {% if clothing_info[0].clothes_specification_id !=1 %} checked="checked" {% else %} {% endif %}>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_existing">vorhandene</label>
              </td>
              <td class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline size_art_inner">
                  <input type="radio" id="radio_specification_none" name="specification" class="custom-control-input" {% if clothing_info[0].clothes_specification_id==1 %} checked="checked" {% else %} {% endif %}>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_specification_none">keine</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```